# Exceção em consulta sql

Tags: php, mysql, select

Como faço para exibir os itens do meu banco de dados MySql em php, para que selecione todos os itens exceto um item.
Ex: tenho vários cadastros...

```
item 1   |   id01
item 2   |   id02
item 3   |   id03
item 4   |   id04
item 5   |   id05
item 6   |   id06
```

Quero exibir todos em php exceto o item com o id04.

meu código...

```
$itemcheck = $dbh->prepare("select * FROM itens ORDER BY it_data DESC");
$itemcheck->execute();
while ( $cm_item = $itemcheck->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_OBJ) ){
}
```

Não sei se fui bem claro na minha pergunta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode exibir todos os registros exceto o de id 4 com usando o operador [diferente/not equal](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_not-equal) `<>` ou `!=`

```
$itemcheck = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM itens WHERE id <> ? ORDER BY it_data DESC");

$itemcheck->execute(array(4));
while ( $cm_item = $itemcheck->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_OBJ) ){

}
```

Comment: Obrigado, resolveu meu problema. :)

Answer (score 2):

Tente ser o mais claro possível em sua pergunta. Aparentemente pelo próprio SQL você resolve.

```
$itemcheck = $dbh->prepare("select * FROM itens where id not in (4) ORDER BY it_data DESC");
```

Answer (score 1):

Não ficou claro o que você quer, mas vamos lá.

Você quer selecionar todas as COLUNAS exceto uma?
Se esse for o caso, você deve passar as colunas que quer usar:

```
select col1,col3,col4,col6 FROM itens ORDER BY it_data DESC
```

Caso queira selecionar todas as linhas, menos uma:

```
SELECT * FROM itens WHERE id != "1" ORDER BY it_data DESC
ou
SELECT * FROM itens WHERE id NOT IN (1) ORDER BY it_data DESC -> (como o Marllon postou)
```